# LOAD DATA INFILE with variables

Tags: c#, mysql, load-data-infile

I was tring to use the LOAD DATA INFILE as a sotred procedure but it seems it cannot be done. Then i tried the usual way of embedding the code to the application itself like so,

```
conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
conn.Open();
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
string tableName = getTableName(serverName);
string query = "LOAD DATA INFILE '" + fileName + "'INTO TABLE "+ tableName +" FIELDS TERMINATED BY '"+colSep+"' ENCLOSED BY '"+colEncap+"' ESCAPED BY '"+colEncap+"'LINES TERMINATED BY '"+colNewLine+"' ("+colUpFormat+");";
cmd.CommandText = query;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

The generated query that gets saved in the string variable query is,

```
        LOAD DATA INFILE 'data_file.csv'INTO TABLE tbl_shadowserver_bot_geo FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '"'LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (timestamp,ip,port,asn,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,url,agent,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy,@dummy);
```

But now when i run the program it gives an error saying,

```
        MySQLException(0x80004005) Parameter @dummy must be defined first.
```

I dont know how to get around this, but when i use the same query on mysql itself directly it works fine. PLEASE help me..thank you very much :)

Comment: I notice there are some spaces missing in your query (.csv'INTO) and  (ESCAPED BY '"'LINES). Check if that is the case in your original query or if its just wrongly posted here.

Comment: hi, thank you for the reply, but it wasn't the issue :) .. i found the solution

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the solution myself, it is to set this condition,

```
      Allow User Variables=true;
```

in the connection string that will allow to use @parameter values in a query :)

Thank you for the responses :)

Answer (score 0):

I too encountered with this problem, then I created the bulk insert script and run it using C#.net code

Comment: sure..i will once i complete testing the suggestion you gave. thanks again :)

Comment: This is simply not true, LOAD DATA INFILE can be used from code.

Comment: I tried it by using code but it does not work .. can you please give any link or code sample which doing same ..

Comment: well yours must be the long way around it seems that there is another easy solution.. i just found it and ill post it as the answer :)

Comment: Ok .. Good this will be also use full for me