# Fatal error during execution (MySQL Bulk Load)

Tags: mysql, .net, vb.net

This simple code returns a 'fatal execution error', but the **same query runs perfectly fine** when executed directly in MySQL:

```
SQL = "LOAD DATA INFILE 'D:\\Shared\\Berlin Stock Exchange\\0002.BE#CLP HOLDINGS ORD (M).csv'  INTO TABLE prices FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'  IGNORE 1 LINES  (@col1,@col2,@col3,@col4,@col5,@col6,@col7,@col8) SET `symbol`=@col1,`int`=@col2,`date`=STR_TO_DATE(@col3,'%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s %p'), `close`=@col7;"
cmd = New MySqlCommand(SQL, conn)
cmd.CommandTimeout = 0
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12834675/load-data-infile-with-variables

Comment: Tim, thank you - you are right. Adding ';Allow User Variables=True' to the connection string did the trick. Please post the answer and I will accept it as a solution. Thanks!